# Age variable Calculation using DATE OF BIRTH

Tags: python

I have a dataframe, which has Date of birth variable and i need to calculate age based on the date of birth variable of given time period using python. Please suggest

Example

```
   DOB         AGE    TIME PERIOD 
31-12-1990     28     01-02-2017
01-01-1987     32     01-02-2017
12-07-1992     26     01-02-2017
```

I need Values for all rows in a AGE Column.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please include the code snippet of what have you tried or [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How is the age getting calculated? I can see the `Age` should be `26, 30, 24` based on `DOB` and `TIME_PERIOD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(filename)
df['DOB']=pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])
df['TIME PERIOD']=pd.to_datetime(df['TIME PERIOD'])
df.insert(1,'AGE',(df['TIME PERIOD']-df['DOB']).astype('<m8[Y]').astype(int))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         DOB  AGE TIME_PERIOD
0 1990-12-31   26  2017-01-02
1 1987-01-01   30  2017-01-02
2 1992-12-07   24  2017-01-02
```

But you will be thinking why the ages are incorrect in my code, but actually if you think about it, my code is right, so that's a fix up too.